# filenet JAVA API retention periode not updated

Tags: java, filenet

I've been working on a project that use filenet for multiple parts of the project.
I've been asked to remove a boatload of file's that need to be removed. The reason why I was asked is because the assumtion was made we could remove the data through a java application.

And so far so good honestly. I've been able to use code left by former project members to create a delete application. However, i've come to a single problem in this issue: the retention date.

When I delete a file it will display the error message: *Content Engine cannot delete or move content because the retention period for the item has not yet expired. Current time: 9/16/21 8:43 AM; Storage period: 20-12-99 1:00.*

I've created code that does change this. However the above error is still appearing. I;ve doubled checked the retentiondate property in the specifice file, and this has been changed.

I've looked through all the properties of the file and have not spotted anything that includes this date.

So my questions is, what am I missing? Is this something from filenet?

Answer (score 0):

The retention period is probably additionally set on the storage device and the storage device is not aligned with filenet.

What type of storage backend are you using.

Comment: We are using SQL database, managed by toad

Answer (score 0):

Please check this doc https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.2.1?topic=objects-retention-limitations-constraints

And this https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.2.1?topic=objects-security-permissions-required-setting-modifying-retention

Sure that you have enough permissions for the principal that you are using for API  calls.

And check this page https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.2.1?topic=sweeps-deleting-objects-sweep and this https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/filenet-p8-platform/5.2.1?topic=sweeps-updating-object-retention as alternative way to delete objects without API and custom app.